# Bar chart: Have values, not percent, on the Y axis, but keep percent and values for every node

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

### Problem Description

I would like to have the node of each bar being the actual value and its corresponding percentage, but on the Y axis I would like to have a scale of values. With my current MWE, I am getting the following output:
[image: graph]

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}


\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{
1,15,5
2,9,11
3,3,6
4,5,6
}\data

\pgfplotsset{
    percentage plot/.style={
        point meta=explicit,
    every node near coord/.append style={
        align=center,
        text width=1cm
    },
        nodes near coords={
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\iszero{\originalvalue==0}
        \ifnum\iszero=0
            \pgfmathprintnumber{\originalvalue}$\,\%$\\ \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=1]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
        \fi},
    nodes near coords align=vertical,
        yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=100,
        enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.18},
    visualization depends on={y \as \originalvalue}
    },
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis on top,
    width=10cm,
    title = Graph,
    ybar,
    percentage plot,bar width=0.75cm,
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4},
    xtick=data,
    xlabel=Response value,
    ylabel=Number of responses,
    legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.2)},
        anchor=north,
            column sep=1ex} 
]
\addplot coordinates {(1,47)[15] (2,28)[9] (3,9)[3] (4,16)[5]};
\addplot coordinates {(1,18)[5] (2,39)[11] (3,21)[6] (4,21)[6]};
\legend{Text 1, Text 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Desired Output/Solution

I would like the Y axis to show values 1, 2, ... ,15 instead of percentages.

Comment: Is it OK to simply swap the y-value and the meta-value in the coordinate list and the `nodes near coords`? So instead of for example `(1,47)[15]` you have `(1,15)[47]`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I tried to modified it a bit but with no luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to swap the y-value and the meta-value in your plot. So instead of for example

```
\addplot coordinates {(1,47)[15] (2,28)[9] (3,9)[3] (4,16)[5]};
```

you have

```
\addplot coordinates {(1,15)[47] (2,9)[28] (3,3)[9] (4,5)[16]};
```

For each coordinate `(x,y)[meta]` the y-value and meta-value are swapped.

And the setting for `nodes near coords` have

```
\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}$\,\%$\\ \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=1]{\originalvalue}
```

instead of

```
 \pgfmathprintnumber{\originalvalue}$\,\%$\\ \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=1]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
```

You can see the that `\pgfplotspointmeta` and `\originalvalue` are swapped in the two.

I just noticed I forgot to change the `ylabel`, so you'll want to fix that.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % loads pgfplots which loads tikz
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{
1,15,5
2,9,11
3,3,6
4,5,6
}\data

\pgfplotsset{
    percentage plot/.style={
        point meta=explicit,
    every node near coord/.append style={
        align=center,
        text width=1cm
    },
        nodes near coords={
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\iszero{\originalvalue==0}
        \ifnum\iszero=0
            \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}$\,\%$\\ \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=1]{\originalvalue}
        \fi},
    nodes near coords align=vertical,
%        yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
        ymin=0,
%        ymax=100,
        enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.18},
    visualization depends on={y \as \originalvalue}
    },
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis on top,
    width=10cm,
    title = Graph,
    ybar,
    percentage plot,bar width=0.75cm,
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4},
    xtick=data,
    xlabel=Response value,
    ylabel=Number of responses,
    legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.2)},
        anchor=north,
            column sep=1ex} 
]
\addplot coordinates {(1,15)[47] (2,9)[28] (3,3)[9] (4,5)[16]};
\addplot coordinates {(1,5)[18] (2,11)[39] (3,6)[21] (4,6)[21]};
\legend{Text 1, Text 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that works, that is exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much! :)